# What is waiting for Shadow in the U.S.?

Tags: american-gods

In the final chapter, when Shadow meets Iceland's version of Odin, he asks if Shadow will return to the U.S..
Shadow answers there is nothing waiting for him there, which he realizes is false, and Odin replies there is something but it will await his return. What is this?